# How to set a non repeating alarm in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, alarmmanager

I am trying to set a non repeating alarm ..but i am not able to do so...When i am setting alarm using below code it alaways repeat in each day. I dont want to repeat the alarm ever in life. When i set the alarm i just get the option of `set` , `setInexactrepeating`. So how to set alarm only once?

```
        alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calender.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making a change in your last two line of Code i.e.

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calender.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

In the above line of code you have used ***".setInexactRepeating"*** that will set a repeating alarm and ***"Alarm Manager.INTERVAL_DAY"*** will force it to repeat it on same time everyday.

Now for setting a non-repeating alarm you suppose to set a EXACT Alarm that can be set as (I am directly putting it blow from Android Developers)

**Set an exact alarm**
The system invokes an exact alarm at a precise moment in the future. If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, you must declare the "Alarms & reminders" special app access; otherwise, a SecurityException occurs.

Your app can set exact alarms using one of the following methods. These methods are ordered such that the ones closer to the bottom of the list serve more time-critical tasks but demand more system resources.

**setExact()**
Invoke an alarm at a nearly precise time in the future, as long as other battery-saving measures aren't in effect.

Use this method to set exact alarms, unless your app's work is time-critical for the user.

**setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()**
Invoke an alarm at a nearly precise time in the future, even if battery-saving measures are in effect.

**setAlarmClock()**
Invoke an alarm at a precise time in the future. Because these alarms are highly visible to users, the system never adjusts their delivery time. The system identifies these alarms as the most critical ones and leaves low-power modes if necessary to deliver the alarms.

Below Link will help you in detail:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: Thanks for your answer..But can you be little more specific with your answer...You gave dozen of paragraphs..but where(what) is the required solution sir ?